# why i have exc_bad_access doing cast?

Tags: c, exc-bad-access

i am programming in C and i have a problem while casting an int into a char.

I am using my mac with Xcode to program c.

The code is:

```
int main(){    
  int t = 2;    
  printf("test %s\n", (char)t); //EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  return 0;
}
```

I tried all I found in many post, I really don't know what is going on... any suggestion?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and heed them. Remember the proper `#include`s. `"%s"` expects a pointer to char (a string); you are passing a character.

Comment: I change the %s in to %c, but still, i dont have bad_access but i have this exit on the console: test ¿ I have all the includes I think i need #include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> #include <string.h>. All warnings are on and i don't have anyone :S

Comment: On your computer, the character with value `2` appears on the console as ¿. You may want to use `int t = 'W';` to have a W printed. Or, assuming your computer uses (some form of) ASCII, `int t = 65;` for an A.

Comment: so what if i want to convert the integer 2 into char '2'?

Comment: add `'0'` to it: `int t = 2; printf("%c", t + '0');` The digits `'0'` through `'9'` are consecutive. The second digit after `'0'` is `'2'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include the goal of your code in your question not in a comment below.

If you want the output

> test 2

your have to change %s to %d

```
printf("test %d\n", t);
```

I guess you got the wrong idea about the `%s`. It does not tell the `printf` that you want to have the **int** as string, it does tell `printf` that the parameter is a string! It is obviously not, so you got the exception.

if you use %c you tell the printf function that you want to output your number as character from your current ASCII table. For example 65 is 'A'.

If you have a concatenation situation like

```
strcpy(str_buscar, "controlID='"); 
strcat(str_buscar, (char) t); 
strcat(str_buscar, "'");
```

you need itoa instead of the cast:

```
strcat(str_buscar, (char) t);
```

you need the follow:

```
char buffer[32]; // enough space for a "number as string"
itoa(t,buffer,10);
strcat(str_buscar, buffer);
```

a (IMHO) shortcut is to "print" to a buffer with `sprintf`

```
sprintf(str_buscar,"controlID='%d'",t);
```

instead of printing to a console `sprintf` prints into the given buffer. Make shure that your buffer str_buscar is big enough.

Comment: Sorry, i am a bit new around here. The goal of the code is to do:     strcpy(str_buscar, "controlID='");
    strcat(str_buscar, (char) t);
    strcat(str_buscar, "'");
and use printf.

Comment: @ Mario Bañares Colastra . Make that part of your question as what you asking for is a little bit different as from what you are asking in your comment. I will extend my answer

Comment: Thanks! I tried and works. Actually I had to do a small change, but everything was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` format specifier represents a string, not an individual character. Printf thinks that the number 2 you're passing it is a string's address. It tries to access the memory address `2` and fails, because that address doesn't exist.

If you want to print a character, you'll want the `%c` specifier. This tells printf to print the character whose ASCII code is 2. The ASCII character number 2 is, [according to the ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/), a control character that cannot be printed, which is why you're getting strange output.

If you actually want to print the character '2' (which has a different code, 50), you will want to use something like:

```
printf("test: %c", (char)('0' + c));
```

This example leverages the fact that all ASCII characters have consecutive codes, starting with 48 ('0'). This way, if you wanted to print the digit 0, you'd end up printing the '0' character (ASCII code 48 = 48 + 0). If you want to print the digit 2, you'll end up printing the '2' character (50 = 48 + 2).

This way, however, is a bit clunky and fails when encountering numbers larger than 9 (i.e. it only works with digits). The easier way consists of no longer working with characters at all and, instead, using the '%d' specifier (used for printing whole number):

```
int t = 0;
printf("test: %d", t);
```